# How do you add the Microsoft Hazel text-to-speech voice back to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

I have had the US version of Windows: previously 8.1 and now 10. In 8.1, Microsoft supplied three text-to-speech voices: Zira, David, and Hazel. Hazel is UK voice and is now missing from Windows 10. Therefore, it seems like a feature has been removed.

Is there way to manually add Hazel back to Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

To add Hazel back into Windows 10

1. Click on the start button
2. Then click settings
3. Within settings go to Time & Language
4. Click Region and Language from the left side
5. In the middle click Add a language
6. Click English
7. Click English (United Kingdom)
8. Click on English (United Kingdom) under your installed languages
9. Click Options
10. From here you can select the Speech option to install with all the other United Kingdom features.

Hope this helps!